# Почему не работают интернет запросы в сборке Unity проекта?

Tags: unity3d

Создал проект. Делаю запросы для регистрации пользователя, авторизации и т.д. В режиме редактора все хорошо работает. Но в сборке ничего не происходит кроме проверки подключения. Использовал и `WWW` и `UnityWebRequest`. Может проблема с `StartCoroutine()` и его нельзя использовать?
Сама сборка выдает такую ошибку:

> NotSupportedException: Encoding 1251 data could not be found. Make
> sure you have correct international code set assembly installed and
> enabled
>
> System. Text. Encoding. GetEncoding (System. Int32 codepage) (at
> :0)
> System. Text. Encoding. GetEncoding (System. String name) (at
> :0)
> UnityEngine Networking Download Handler Get Зарегестрироваться
> <9195dbf69dc249a6bdd7df7af2699f7d>:0)
> UnityEngine. Networking. Download Handler Gettext (I (at <9195dbf69dc249a6bdd7df7a 2699f7d> 0)
> UnityEngine. Networking. Download Handler gettext () (at <9195dbf69dc249a6bdd7df7af2699f7d>:0)
> Mysql Connect+d36.MoveNext () (at
> D:/UnityProjects/CoymeAssignment/Assets/Contrd Scripts: Mysql Connect.cs: 213)
> Unity Engine.Setup Coroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System. Collections. I Enumerator enumerator,
> international code set assembly installed and enabled.
> Not Supported Exception: Encoding 1251 data could not be found. Make sure you have correct
> international code set assembly installed and enabled.
> 5
> WebGL
> Lear
> Player Settings...
> Build

Comment: `Использовал и WWW и UnityWebRequest`. В текущей версии Unity `WWW` - это просто обёртка над `UnityWebRequest` (:

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что ваша проблема связана с Code Stripping в Unity. Иными словами, в редакторе определенные классы/библиотеки присутствуют, а при сборке билда сброщик юнити считает, что они не нужны и вырезает их. Это можно попробовать исправить в вашей ситуации:

- Попробуйте уменьшить уровень Code Stripping в проекте или вовсе его выключить. [Мануал по Code Stripping](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeStripping.html) в юнити. Соберите билд и попробуйте проверить, не исправило ли это ошибку.
- Скопируйте библиотеки I18N.dll и I18N.West.dl в директорию вашего проекта.Соберите билд и попробуйте проверить, не исправило ли это ошибку.
- Если предыдущее действие не помогло, то в добавок попробуйте также следующее. Найдите в папке Assets файл link.xml (или создайте его) и добавьте в него строки:

> ```
> <linker>
> <assembly fullname="I18N" preserve="all"/>
> <assembly fullname="I18N.West" preserve="all"/>
> </linker>
> ```

Иснова соберите билд и проверьте.

Решение похожей проблемы обсуждалось в 2 темах на оффициальном форуме, можете глянуть [здесь](https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-application-crash-with-notsupportedexception.415325/) и [здесь](https://answers.unity.com/questions/42955/codepage-1252-not-supported-works-in-editor-but-no.html)

Answer (score 0):

При ошибках типа Encoding 1251, Encoding 1252 и т.д. скопируйте эти файлы из папки Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\unity в ваш проект: 
I18N.dll, I18N.CJK.dll, I18N.MidEast.dll, I18N.Other.dll, I18N.Rare.dll, I18N.West.dll

Это файлы локализации. Не все они нужны одновременно, но какой из них отвечает за какую именно ошибку - не понятно.
На момент запуска приложения в редакторе, эти файлы присутствуют под рукой у Юнити, а в билд они не включаются. Почему Юнити не отслеживает их использование  - не понятно.

[image: Решение: скопировать файлы локализации в проект]
Решение было найдено в этой англоязычной теме: https://answers.unity.com/questions/42955/codepage-1252-not-supported-works-in-editor-but-no.html